# `Warning (bytecomp)` is a bit vague - can I get any more information?

Tags: byte-compilation, warning

When I start emacs, I get a couple of byte compilation warnings in a window that pops up:

```
Warning (bytecomp): `interactive-p' is an obsolete function (as of 23.2); use `called-interactively-p' instead. [7 times]
Warning (bytecomp): Use `with-current-buffer' rather than save-excursion+set-buffer
```

Can I get emacs to give me locations?

Comment: This info would be useful to everyone. Use M-x `report-emacs-bug` to request this feature.

Comment: If you try to set `debug-on-message` to `Warning (bytecomp)`, won't it trigger the debugger?

Comment: IIRC you do get file names when Emacs knows the file.  So presumably the above comes from some Elisp code which was "generated on the fly" rather than saved to a file and then passed to the byte-compiler.  In 99% of the cases, starting Emacs should actually not compile any code at all, so maybe the problem can be fixed at an even higher level.

Comment: @wvxvw - I didn't manage to make `debug-on-message` do anything.

In the end, the `interactive-p` turned out to be caused by screen-lines.el, and the `with-current-buffer` one was due to an ancient version of tuareg-mode.

I decided to remove both. I don't use tuareg-mode, and while I quite like screen-lines.el, it's long caused me all sorts of problems with keyboard macros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens due to `display-warning` delaying warnings until after init time.  By then, the file name and location are no longer known.

```el
(defun display-warning (type message &optional level buffer-name)
  [...]
  (if (not (or after-init-time noninteractive (daemonp)))
      ;; Ensure warnings that happen early in the startup sequence
      ;; are visible when startup completes (bug#20792).
      (delay-warning type message level buffer-name)
    (unless level
    [... ]
```

You should be able to disable this with some advice:

```el
(defun dont-delay-compile-warnings (fun type &rest args)
  (if (eq type 'bytecomp)
      (let ((after-init-time t))
        (apply fun type args))
    (apply fun type args)))
(advice-add 'display-warning :around #'dont-delay-compile-warnings)
```

Although this might prevent the `*Warnings*` buffer from popping up (as described in Bug#20792), so you'll have to check it manually in the `*Compile-Log*` buffer.

Previous case of this, reported on emacs-devel [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2017-01/msg00290.html) ([continues here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2017-02/msg00625.html)).

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to guess the warnings are coming from on-the-fly compilation of ELPA packages. Try running the following code:

```
(defun my-package-recompile()
  "Recompile all packages"
  (interactive)
  (byte-recompile-directory "~/.emacs.d/elpa" 0 t))
```

After M-x my-package-recompile switch the the *Compile-Log* buffer and see if these warnings are replicated in there?

Comment: I have the same problem but only the first error and 2 times. This solution didn't work. Also, it said `Done (Total of 4 files compiled, 1 failed, 2 skipped in 3 directories)`.

Comment: Sorry, thought this was about fixing the problem, not obtaining more information. I tried looking for the error now but it didn't appear in the list.